# ¿como realizar login con correo en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy intentando hacer un login en Django y he visto que por defecto solo puedo logearme con el nombre de usuario y la contraseña pero por exigencias de mi cliente quiere que se pueda loguear con el email aparte del nombre de usuario.

He creado una función a partir de la que viene en Django para validar las cuentas pero tengo un error que no entiendo.

La función es:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def login_user (request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('home')
else:
    message = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            if '@' in username:
                kwargs = {'email': username}
            else:
                kwargs = {'username': username}
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return redirect('home')
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                form = LoginForm()
                return redirect('home')
```

Al enviar el request a la función login() de Django da este error:

> You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.

setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.instagram.InstagramOAuth2',
'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2')
```

Comment: Hola, muestra tu settings.py, sobre todo la parte en la que configuras los backends.

Comment: añadido a la pregunta

Comment: Si estás buscando buenos cursos de python (de pago), este sitio es una joyita: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un metodo propio de backend asi:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailLogon(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None


def get_user(self, user_id):
   try:
      return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
   except User.DoesNotExist:
      return None
```

Y determina el backend en el settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.auth.module.EmailBackend']
```

Heredar de ModelBackend te permite usar los metodos que ves en la función, como por ejemplo user.check_password(password)

Comment: Tengo una duda sobre esta forma, en mi caso tengo también un backend propio, aparte del admin de Django, si añado esto me afectaría también a ese backend? es que quiero separar ambos accesos para que los usuarios del backend entren solo con el usuario y no con el correo.

Comment: Una vez que haya añadido esto en el backend, que debo añadir en mi función de login? sigue dandome el mismo error